# Finding matching letters in a string at same spots

Tags: c++

I need a code to compare two strings: `word` and `ptw`. Both strings only have one word, and are of equal length and same case. The code needs to check the first character of both words and see if they are same and it will do this untill the end of the word. Then it will output the amount of matching letters (I don't need to know the matching letters).

Example: If `word` is `windows` and `ptw` is `winowes` it should output `4` as `w`, `i`, `n`, and `s` match.

I have tried the following however it does not check the positions:

```
string matchingletters(string word, string ptw) {

    string result = "";
    sort(begin(word), end(word));
    sort(begin(ptw), end(ptw));
    std::string intersection;
    std::set_intersection(begin(word), end(word), begin(ptw), end(ptw),
        back_inserter(intersection));
    string mlr = to_string(intersection.length());
    result = mlr + result;
    cout << result << endl;
    return result;

}
```

The result this gives when `word` is `kanton` and `ptw` is `balkon` is `4`.
It counts `k` even though `k` is at `0` position in word and `3` position at ptw and thus they are not in the same postion and should not be counted.

Comment: 1. Not homework 2. I already know I can compare it one by one but I want a more simplified version perhaps using iterators 3. This is a function of my code.

Comment: @ozanesici : What Aseroids With Wings means is that you need to state what you have tried and what you are stuck on.  You should read [How to Ask a Good Question (Stack Overflow Help Center)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I just want to learn a more proper way of doing it and as I could not find any others after looking it up and trying it on my own I then posted it here.

Comment: I have edited the post with what I tried.

Comment: @LakshyaRaj I appreciate the warnings and taking it slow with me as I am new to the site.

Comment: What do you mean by _"it does not check the positions"_? Give full detail about your problem.

Comment: I have edited the post with a sample run @AsteroidsWithWings

Comment: I don't understand how your code relates to the stated problem. You're supposed to be checking for characters matching "at the same spots", yet you sort both inputs at the very start of your algorithm, immediately losing those positions. I suggest you step through the problem with a pencil and some paper.

Comment: @ozanesici : Will the two words be the same length?

Comment: yes @LakshyaRaj

Comment: I see my mistake there now @AsteroidsWithWings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the two words have the same length and since you don't care which letters match you can simply iterate and count matching characters

```cpp
unsigned matchingletters(const std::string& word, const std::string& ptw) {
    assert(word.size() == ptw.size());

    unsigned count{0};
    for (size_t i = 0; i < word.size(); ++i) {
        if(word[i] == ptw[i])
            count++;
    }

    return count;
}
```